# React - Type 'number | MutableRefObject<any>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I want to add ref to the main element, below error occurs.

Error

```
Type 'number | MutableRefObject<any>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLElement>'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLElement>'
```

How to fix it?

index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import useScrollPercentage from "./useScrollPercentage";

// reset styles
Object.assign(document.body.style, {
  overflow: "hidden",
  margin: "0"
});

function App() {
  const [scrollRef, scrollPercentage] = useScrollPercentage();

  return (
    // attach scrollRef to scroll container
    <main ref={scrollRef} style={{ height: "100vh", overflowY: "scroll" }}>
      {/* Simulate overflowing content */}
      <div style={{ height: 3000 }} />

      {/* Display scroll percentage */}
      <h1 style={{ position: "fixed", top: 10, left: 10 }}>
        {`${scrollPercentage}%`}
      </h1>
    </main>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

useScrollPercentage.js

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useScrollPercentage() {
  const scrollRef = useRef(null);
  const [scrollPercentage, setScrollPercentage] = useState(NaN);

  const reportScroll = e => {
    setScrollPercentage(getScrollPercentage(e.target));
  };

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const node = scrollRef.current;
      if (node !== null) {
        node.addEventListener("scroll", reportScroll, { passive: true });
        if (Number.isNaN(scrollPercentage)) {
          setScrollPercentage(getScrollPercentage(node));
        }
      }
      return () => {
        if (node !== null) {
          node.removeEventListener("scroll", reportScroll);
        }
      };
    },
    [scrollPercentage]
  );

  return [scrollRef, Number.isNaN(scrollPercentage) ? 0 : scrollPercentage];
}

function getScrollPercentage(element) {
  if (element === null) {
    return NaN;
  }
  const height = element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight;
  return Math.round((element.scrollTop / height) * 100);
}
```

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-percentage-hook-forked-6bcyw?file=/src/index.tsx

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function useScrollPercentage() {
  // ...
  return [scrollRef, Number.isNaN(scrollPercentage) ? 0 : scrollPercentage];
}
```

Since you havn't given an explicit return type, typescript has to infer one. It's going to assume this is an array, not a tuple, and so the array has type `(MutableRefObject<any> | number)[]`, since it contains both ref objects and numbers. This type doesn't have any information about what elements are in what positions of the array, so back in App it's not clear whether scrollRef is a ref or a number.

If you want the type to be a tuple `[MutableRefObject<any>, number]`, you need to give it a type yourself. You can either do this:

```
export default function useScrollPercentage(): [MutableRefObject<any>, number] {
```

Or you can keep using type inference, but use `as const` to give typescript a hint so that it infers a stricter type:

```
return [scrollRef, Number.isNaN(scrollPercentage) ? 0 : scrollPercentage] as const;
```